# Exploding an Array to create Tags?

Tags: php, arrays, tags

I'm trying to separate a string by commas and output as tags formatted by html.

When I do this:

```
$str = perch_member_get('skill');
$arr = explode(",",$str);
print_r($arr);
```

I get this as my output in the page:

```
Array ( [0] => Web Design [1] => Web Development [2] => Film Editing )
```

1. How do I remove the Array and Numbering information and just have the words
2. How do I format each word with html and css styling?

Comment: `foreach($arr as $val){ echo $val; }`

Comment: try this `echo "<p>".implode("</p><p>", $arr)."</p>";`